# How is this nested Groovy statement interpreted in terms of the arguments of `timeout()`?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, timeout, closures, jenkins-groovy

What syntax/construct is used in the following Groovy code? It seems like two statements nested inside each other.

What are the arguments of the `timeout()` function in the following code? It is a function or a reserved word?

Is the `input(...)` statement a Groovy "Closure"? Is it a third argument of the function `timeout`?

```
    timeout(time: 5, unit: 'MINUTES') {
        input(message: 'Please approve')
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following `timeout` and `input` definitions will work in plain groovy:

```
def input(Map params){
    println "input $params"
}

def timeout(Map params, Closure c){
    println "timeout $params"    
    c.call()
    println "timeout after"    
}


timeout(time: 5, unit: 'MINUTES') {
    input(message: 'Please approve')
}
```

output:

```
timeout [time:5, unit:MINUTES]
input [message:Please approve]
timeout after
```

Comment: Thank you. This perfect example fully answers all my questions.